# How do I input c struct pointer in javascript with ffi?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, ffi

I am trying to pass a pointer to `struct` to a method from nodejs with ffi.
But I am getting following error. It's not able to determine the type of 
javascript struct I have created. How do I fix it?

**For similar methods with `int*,double*` etc.. I am able to make it work.**

**learn.h**

```
struct myobj
{
  int a;
};

extern "C"  void create_object(struct myobj*);
```

**learn.cc**

```
void create_object(struct myobj* obj)
{
  return;
}
```

**learn.js**

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var Struct = require('ref-struct');
...
var myObj = Struct(
  {
    'a': 'int'
  }
);

var myObjPtr = ref.refType(myObj);
...
var learn = ffi.Library(mathlibLoc, {
    'create_object': ['void',[myObjPtr]]
});

module.exports = learn;
```

**test.js**

```
var learn = require('./learn.js');
...
var blah = ref.alloc('myObj');
learn.create_object(blah);
```

> throw new TypeError('could not determine a proper "type" from: ' +
>   JSON.stringify(type))
>       ^
>
> TypeError: could not determine a proper "type" from: "myObjPtr"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out a solution for this.

**learn.js**

```
module.exports = {learn,myObj};
```

**test.js**

```
var labh = ref.alloc(learn.myObj);
learn.learn.create_object(blah);
```

We have to export the variable and do proper scope selection of the object.